# Have a problem with php code, runs, but won't execute

Tags: php

The search procedure is affecting the sort of procedure.
If I test each one by itself, they both work.
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with mysqli_fetch_array($results)
I just can’t find where I’m going wrong.
Any assistance would really be appreciated.

Server:test  Table:testcode
id, FirstName, LastName

index.php

```php
<?php
include('new.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Code</title>
<style>
table,tr,th,td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-sbi">
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="valueToSearch"  placeholder="Value To Search"> 
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search"  value="Search">
</div>     
<form method="post" action="index.php" >
<div class="input-group">
<div id="content1">     
<label>FirstName</label>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $FirstName; ?>">
<label>LastName</label>
<input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $LastName; ?>"> 
</select><br><br> 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
</div>
</div>  
<table> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th><a href="?orderby=id&order=<?php echo $idOrder; ?>">id</a></th>
<th><a href="?orderby=FirstName&order=<?php echo $FirstNameOrder; ? 
>">FirstName</a></th>
<th><a href="?orderby=LastName&order=<?php echo $LastNameOrder; ? 
>">LastName</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
<td>
<a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id'];? 
>"class="edit_btn">Edit</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="index.php?del=<?php echo $row['id'];? 
>"class="del_btn">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>  
</form>
</body>                
</html>


<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$FirstName = "";
$LastName = "";
$id = 0;
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
$id = $_GET['edit'];
$db=null;
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die("Not 
connected.");
$record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM testcode WHERE id=$id");
if (@count($record) == 1 ) {
$n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
$FirstName = $n['FirstName'];
$LastName = $n['LastName'];
}
}
// Ascending Decending Order
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$orderBy = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? $_GET["orderby"] : "id";
$order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? $_GET["order"] : "asc";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testcode ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;
$result = $db->query($sql);
$idOrder = "asc";
$FirstNameOrder = "asc";
$LastNameOrder = "asc";
if($orderBy == "id" && $order == "asc") {
$idOrder = "desc";
}
if($orderBy == "FirstName" && $order == "asc") {
$FirstNameOrder = "desc";
}
if($orderBy == "LastName" && $order == "asc") {
$LastNameOrder = "desc";
}
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `testcode` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `FirstName`, 
`LastName`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
$results = filterTable($query);
}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `testcode`";
$results = filterTable($query);
}
function filterTable($query)
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
return $filter_Result;
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you make 3 connections? why do you mix procedural with oop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change PHP code as described follows. In addition, you missed some tags and added unused tags, I added comments for your understanding:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('new.php');

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$FirstName = "";
$LastName = "";
$id = 0;
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];

    // --- Unnecessary db connection start ---
    // $db=null;
    // $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die("Not connected.");      
    // --- Unnecessary db connection start ---

    $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM testcode WHERE id=$id");

    if (@count($record) == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
        $FirstName = $n['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $n['LastName'];
    }
}
// Ascending Decending Order 

// --- Unnecessary db connection start ---
// $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");   
// --- Unnecessary db connection end ---

$orderBy = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? $_GET["orderby"] : "id";
$order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? $_GET["order"] : "asc";

// --- Unnecessary query start ---
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM testcode ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;
// $result = $db->query($sql);
// --- Unnecessary query end ---

$idOrder = "asc";
$FirstNameOrder = "asc";
$LastNameOrder = "asc";

if($orderBy == "id" && $order == "asc") {
    $idOrder = "desc";
}
if($orderBy == "FirstName" && $order == "asc") {
    $FirstNameOrder = "desc";
}
if($orderBy == "LastName" && $order == "asc") {
    $LastNameOrder = "desc";
}
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

    // Add order by clause at the end of query to apply both Search and Order By functionality
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `testcode` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;

    // Pass new paramter called $connect, for not initializing db connection again
    $results = filterTable($query, $db);
}
else {
    // Add order by clause at the end of query to apply only Order By functionality
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `testcode` ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;

    // Pass new paramter called $connect, for not initializing db connection again
    $results = filterTable($query, $db);
}

// Add new paramter called $connect, for not initializing db connection again
function filterTable($query, $connect) {        
    // --- Unnecessary query start ---
    // $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    // --- Unnecessary query start ---

    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
?>
```

Do above changes and then try. Hope may helpful to you!

Comment: If this answer works for you, then please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys; I tried your suggestion Dhara Bhatti, the same result.
I should mention, there are two separate files index.php (html) and new.php(php code).
The search part in (new.php) does work, the sorting in (new.php) does not (the code by itself does work but not together with search).
Example, within the table, clicking on Id, FirstName or LastName would sort that column by ascending or descending.

Comment: Please, anymore ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I think the PHP code displayed in your question is for both sorting and searching, and you are telling that these PHP code is in new.php? Am I understanding right or not? If not, then please correct me.

Comment: There must be one person here, that has a solution.

Comment: Please see my updated code, I added comments for your reference. Please try once and if working, then please accept this answer.

Comment: Perfect, works like I wanted. Had to remove include('new.php');, Just in case someone want's to use part or all of it. Thanks again, your the best.